# Haskell & Language Design: Design Struggle in implementing Do-While Loop for imperative language

Tags: parsing, haskell

I'm designing an imperative language but I'm having issues in implementing loop functionality. A loop would take the following form:

```
Do (n < 10)->
          Loop Body
```

I can parse a loop correctly however when it comes to evaluating the loop, two problems arise. The first is I can't exit loop without returning a faux exit success code, though I do think it's because of how I'm implementing the loop. The second issue is that I can't evaluate the body of the loop when there exists more than one expression. I discovered this because I originally had my loop represented as follows:

```
data HVal
  = HInteger Integer
  | HBool    Bool
  | HString  String
  | HList    [HVal]
  | Expr    HVal Op HVal  -- Arithmetic, Relational, and Boolean 
  | Assign  String HVal 
  | Do      HVal  HVal
```

In this instance the following evaluation function for a loop works when the body consists of a single expression:

```
evalDo :: Env -> HVal -> HVal -> IOThrowsError HVal
evalDo env cond expr = eval env cond >>= \x -> case x of
                                                  HBool True  -> eval env expr >>= \y -> eval env $ Do cond y
                                                  HBool False -> return $ HInteger 1
```

This function evaluates the following loop correctly:

```
n := 0
Do (n < 10)->
             n := (n + 1)
```

When it came to evaluating a longer loop body I found that it made more sense to change the loop representation to:

```
Do HVal [HVal]
```

My logic behind this is that a loop will consist of the guard and then a list of expressions to be evaluated upon in the loop body. I then made a change to `evalDo`:

```
evalDo :: Env -> HVal -> [HVal] -> IOThrowsError HVal
evalDo env cond expr = eval env cond >>= \x -> case x of
                                                           HBool False -> return $ HInteger 1
                                                           HBool True  -> do
                                                                   y  <- return $ map (\x -> eval env x) expr
                                                                   eval env $ Do cond expr
```

This however causes the following loop to go into an infinite loop:

```
n := 0
r := 1

Do (n < 10)->
             n := (n + 1)
             r := (r * 2)
```

I think the problem stems from the return when I evaluate the expression but I receive the following error when I don't have it:

```
Couldn't match type ‘[]’ with ‘ExceptT HError IO’
      Expected type: ExceptT HError IO (IOThrowsError HVal)
        Actual type: [IOThrowsError HVal]
```

Any guidance or help on this would be great.

Comment: Is this meant to be an imperative language? Usually, in the semantics of such a language, one needs to take as an argument a state, e.g. a map `Map Var Value`, which represents the current values of the variables. This map is updated on assignment, which returns the new map. We usually have `semantics :: Progr -> State -> State`. Once you understand how to run an assignment, you will have a clearer idea about loops, so I suggest to start from there.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The first is I can't exit loop without returning a faux exit success code, though I do think it's because of how I'm implementing the loop.

To avoid that issue, imperative languages commonly define their syntax in two levels, *expressions*, like `1 + 2`, which have values, and *statements*, like loops, which don't have values, but their point is their side effects. Expressions are also often considered a subset of statements by ignoring their value. Following that approach, your syntax could be reorganized to look like this:

```hs
data Expr
  = HInteger Integer
  | Expr Expr Op Expr

data Stmt
  = Block [Stmt]
  | Do Expr Stmt
  | Assign Var Expr  -- In C, an assignment is actually an expression, but it is widely considered a misfeature.
  | Eval_ Expr
```

---

> (...) This however causes the following loop to go into an infinite loop:

In your interpretation of `Do`, you are using `map`, which only constructs a list of computations, but you need to compose those computations into a single one.

Use `traverse_` from `Data.Foldable`.

```
  -- traverse_ (\x -> eval env x) expr
  -- or shorter, --
  traverse_ (eval env) expr
  eval env ...
```

---

As a tip for diagnosing that issue, you can tell that something is wrong from reading the code because `y <- return ...`, where `y` is not used later, is always a noop, so

```
  _ <- return $ map (\x -> eval env x) expr
  eval env ...
```

because of `return`, that is the same as

```
  eval env ...
```

whereas you didn't mean to ignore the `map ...` part.

Comment: Would you be able to explain further about composing my list of computations into a single one and the second code block with `_ <- return _`? I'm not quite sure what you mean. Is `traverse_` a way to compose the list of computations into a single one?

Comment: Yes that's what `traverse_` is for. The `_ <- return _` thing is just a side remark to point out why your program is incorrect, it just ignores the whole `map` part.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm assuming as well that splitting up the expressions and statements is a better design choice as well?

Comment: That's right. Let me add a signposting sentence about that.

Comment: Great! Thank you!